# How to avoid rebuilding Google api client each time you make an api request python

Tags: python, django, api, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

In my Django web application i have this function that makes a request to google's youtube api, this function gets excuted each time a user submits a form
Here is the code:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

def myFunc():
      youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey=api_key)

    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="id",
        maxResults=25,
        q="surfing",
    )
    youtube_api_response = request.execute()

    for object in youtube_api_response["items"]:
      # my logic here
```

Now building the api client using

```
googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name, api_version, developerKey=api_key)
```

So building this way each time a user submits a form will require a lot of time and slow down the website.
Is there a way to store this build somehow or reuse the same one each time without the need of building again and again to improve the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to have a single instance of your client. You could then pass that client to the function you want to use.
Even better, wrap your client in a class of its own and simply just call functions from that. Such as:

```html
import googleapiclient.discovery

class GoogleClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_service_name = "name"
        self.api_key = "key"
        self.api_version = "version"
        self.client = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        self.api_service_name, self.api_version, developerKey=self.api_key)
        
    def search(self, q):
        request = self.client.search().list(
            part="id",
            maxResults=25,
            q=q,
        )
        youtube_api_response = request.execute()

        for object in youtube_api_response["items"]:
            print("do whatever")
            

client = GoogleClient()
client.search("query")
```

Comment: Thank you that's a way more cleaner to do it, but like this i would still need to rebuild each time, and it will still take that time to build in each execution wouldn't it? , because my goal is performance, if what you suggested is like what i described can you please explain it?

Comment: No. When you instanitate the object in the line client = GoogleClient(), that is the only time that the client is built.